# Windows Server 2016 completely turn off auto-reboot after updates

Tags: windows-server-2016, automatic-updates

I want to make sure that Windows Server 2016 will definitely not reboot after an update has been manually installed.

The active hours only allow me to set 12 hours of active time unfortunately, and, for example, last week, we manually installed an update which is now asking for a reboot but only want to reboot this coming Friday.

However, I keep having to change the active hours every 12 hours as otherwise this thing will reboot by itself.

Is there no way of disabling auto-restart after an update has been installed? (since the active hours window is so small)

I know about the disable automatic restart for logged on users, but that's not as reliable.

I'm just dumbfounded that there isn't a GP for this. The usual choices in the GP don't apply in this case as, though they're set to download only, an update has already been manually installed and the server is wanting to reboot outside of its active hours...

I do know that certain updates are very critical and hence Server 2012 and such would do an automatic restart in 48 hours or so (I never worked out how to turn that off either aside from turning the Windows Update service off)

Is turning the windows update service off in 2016 as well the only surefire option to prevent it from rebooting itself outside of active hours?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, the only *surefire* solution is to not install the update until you are ready to reboot.  (It isn't like it is doing you any good in the meantime.)

Comment: I was afraid that was the only solution unfortunately... Thanks.

Comment: I frequently use the GPO setting "download but manually install"; this prevents reboots completely - except manual stuff.

Comment: Yes, sadly, that's what I have to end up using...

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to install a patch and then wait for the reboot - you are in a hybrid mode that you do NOT want to be in - patch and then reboot. Do not patch and wait - you are not getting the value of the patch - if you are just looking to pass an audit, you are cheating.

Patch or Die - it is that easy (and reboot is part of some patches)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the description from this link will help you:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2016/10/25/__trashed/

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. When the link breaks, your answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question. Please include at least a summary so the answer can stand on its own. Thank you!

Comment: The link won't help anyway - it just talks about the sconfig command, which only gives you three basic options for Windows Update, none of which do what the OP is asking for.  You can't do anything with sconfig that you can't do with group policy.

Comment: Yup, @harry_johnston is right, it's of no use.